# Имеется ли в C++ литера для мнимой еденицы?

Tags: c++, qt, математика, vector, формулы

Пишу программу для генератора сигналов на Qt C++. Нужно создать сигнал по средствам exp, т.е привести к виду y = A * exp^(i(phi)), **но я не знаю как записать мнимую единицу**. Y в комплексном виде объявил std::complex y ;. На нынешнем этапе разработки записываю сигнал через косинус. Пример генерации сигнала :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() //ЛЧМ импульс
{
    Vector_clear();
         for(X = xBegin_2 ; X<= xEnd_2; X += h)
         {
             x_rab = A*cos((X*0)+(2*pi*d_f*(X*X))/(2*xEnd_2));
             Vector_push_back(x_rab);
         }
         draw_graph();
         for(X = xEnd_2 ; X<= new_T; X += h)
         {
             x_rab = 0;
             Vector_push_back(x_rab);
         }
        draw_graph();
}
```

```
void MainWindow::Vector_clear()
{
    ui->widget->clearGraphs();
    x.clear();
    y.clear();
}
```

```
double MainWindow::Vector_push_back(double x_rab)
{
    x.append(X);
    y.append(x_rab);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если есть поддержка C++14, то можно использовать суффикс i

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std::complex_literals;
auto value = std::exp( 1. + 2.i  );
```

Для более ранних версий, можно ввести глобальную константу:

```
constexpr std::complex<double> _i = { 0, 1 }; // или const для c++ < 11
auto value2 = std::exp( 1. + 2.*_i  );
```

Или, вводить комплексные числа непосредственно через конструктор std::complex с двумя аргументами. Тогда отдельная константа не понадобится.

```
auto value3= std::exp( std::complex<double>(1., 2.) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Начните с [`#include<complex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

А работая с комплексными числами, вы можете использовать [соответствующие литералы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) и писать что-то типа

```
std::complex<double> c = 1.0 + 1i;
```

Впрочем, и без литералов можно записать что-то типа

```
std::complex<double> uno{0.0,1.0};
```